# Send event form IOS to JS

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, react-native

I m trying to repeat Facebook React-Native example with a little difference -and got in trouble, that my Js code don't get events from Objective-C. And events from JS to Objective-C works perfect I spend hours trying to found that's going wrong. Can anybody find where is myistake?

InputTextFieldManager.h

```
@interface InputTextFieldManager : RCTViewManager <RCTBridgeModule>
@end
```

InputTextFieldManager.m

```
#import "InputTextFieldManager.h"

#import "InputTextFieldView.h"
#import "RCTBridge.h"

@interface InputTextFieldManager () <UITextFieldDelegate>

@end

@implementation InputTextFieldManager

@synthesize bridge = _bridge;

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(shouldChangeCharacters, RCTBubblingEventBlock)

RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(titleLabelText, NSString *)
RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(textFieldPlaceholder, NSString *)

- (UIView *)view {
    InputTextFieldView *view = [InputTextFieldView view];
    view.textField.delegate = self;
    return view;
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(sentMessage:(NSString *)message) {
    NSLog(@"JS sent message %@", message);
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:    (NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSLog(@"Entered characters: %@", string);
    InputTextFieldView *view = (id)textField.superview;
    view.shouldChangeCharacters(@{@"replacementString" : string});
    return YES;
}

@end
```

InputTextField.h

```
@interface InputTextFieldView: UIView

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;

@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *titleLabelText;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *textFieldPlaceholder;

@property (nonatomic, copy) RCTBubblingEventBlock shouldChangeCharacters;

+ (instancetype)view;

@end
```

InputTextFieldView.m

```
@interface InputTextFieldView ()

@end

@implementation InputTextFieldView

+ (instancetype)view {
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
    InputTextFieldView *view = [[bundle loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([self class]) owner:nil options:nil] firstObject];
    return view;
}

- (void)setTextFieldPlaceholder:(NSString *)textFieldPlaceholder {
    self.textField.placeholder = textFieldPlaceholder;
}

- (void)setTitleLabelText:(NSString *)titleLabelText {
    self.titleLabel.text = titleLabelText;
}

@end
```

Js code of element

```
import React from 'react';

import { requireNativeComponent } from 'react-native';

class InputTextField extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
                super();
                console.log("start");
    this._shouldChangeCharacters = this._shouldChangeCharacters.bind(this);
  }
  _shouldChangeCharacters(event: Event) {

    console.log("InputTextField. _shouldChangeCharacters was called");

    if (!this.props.myShouldChangeCharacters) {

      return;

    }
    this.props.myShouldChangeCharacters("TEST!");
  }


  render() {
    console.log("InputTextField.render: ", InputTextFieldView)
    return <InputTextFieldView {...this.props} shouldChangeCharacters={this._shouldChangeCharacters} />;
  }
}

InputTextField.propTypes = {

  myShouldChangeCharacters: React.PropTypes.func,
  shouldChangeCharacters: React.PropTypes.func,

  titleLabelText: React.PropTypes.string,
  textFieldPlaceholder: React.PropTypes.string
};
var InputTextFieldView = requireNativeComponent('InputTextField', InputTextField);
module.exports = InputTextField;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(For one of my apps, the event name is "commandCenterEvent", with the eventBody being casted from a NSDictionary literal to a Javascript object)

From ObjC Side (your module):

```
        [_bridge.eventDispatcher sendDeviceEventWithName:@"commandCenterEvent" body:@{
            @"eventType" : @"play"
        }];
```

On your JS side:

```
const RCTDeviceEventEmitter = require('RCTDeviceEventEmitter');

// ... in your class somewhere

    RCTDeviceEventEmitter.addListener(
        'commandCenterEvent',
        (eventObject) => {
            var eventType = eventObject.eventType;

            if (eventType == 'fileLoad') {
                this.eventObject = eventObject;

                this.emit('fileLoaded', eventObject);
            }
            else if (eventType == 'play' || eventType == 'playSleep') {
                this.emitPlay();
            }
            else if (eventType == 'pause' || eventType == 'pauseSleep') {
                this.emitPause();
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: Sadly, i still can't figure out thats going wrong. Your example seems so right and simple, but i put your code into mine and nothing happens
I put RCTDeviceEventEmitter.addListener into constructor of InputTextField and take your Obj-C example. Still nothing logs into Chrome

Comment: Is it possible to say from my code why my bridge didn't set?